# Blinking color sequence in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I have a task to create 4 blinking divs in an Angular project. The colors come from an API in an array with 16 elements and each element is an array with 4 elements (string).

```
ColorPatterns[
  Pattern1["Color1", "Color2", "Color3", "Color4"],
  Pattern2["Color1", "Color2", "Color3", "Color4"],
  ...
  Pattern16["Color1", "Color2", "Color3", "Color4"],
]
```

Color1 is for the first div, Color2 is for the second div and so on. 
The sequence of 16 must change per 1 second and after the last element (Pattern16) the sequence should start over: Pattern1 -> Pattern2 -> ... -> Pattern16 -> Pattern1 -> ... .
How should this problem be solved in Angular?

Comment: Well, how far is your own code to this? I can't imagine that you got this task without having ever written any line of code yourself. This page is not supposed to do your homework, but to help you finding the errors in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Observable to do the timing stuff. If we can to it for one `div` then others can be repeated.

```
Observable.interval(1000) //emit every 1 sec with values = 0 then 1 them 2 ..
    .map(value=>ColorPaterns[value%16][0]) // 0 for 1st color
    .subscribe((firstColor)=>{
        // set 1st div color here
    })
```